# R : adding the values in a [row,column] only if value is true in (same) row, (different) column

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, row, calculated-columns

This is what I'm trying to code for in R...

Let's say I have 50 rows and 4 columns. If the value in (row 1, column 2) was greater than 5, then count the value in (row 1, column 4).

For an example: (row,column)

If (1,2) = (6) then count the value in (1,4)

If (2,2) = (8) then count the value in (2,4)

If (3,2) = (4) then DO NOT count the value in (3,4)

And so on....Then add the all the values from column 4.

How would I code this in R? I've tried creating a function, looping, if statements, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be too hard! Just subset your `data.frame` or `matrix` (however your data is stored) to include only the values of the fourth column, only taking the rows for which the second column is greater than five.

```
sum(yourDataFrame[yourDataFrame[ ,2] > 5, 4])
```

Because many R functions are vectorized, it is often far easier (and faster!) to use vectorized functions like `sum()` than to loop. `yourDataFrame[ ,2] > 5` will return a logical vector. Applying `sum()` to that vector will treat the `TRUE` entries as 1 and the `FALSE` entries as 0, thus providing a count of the values in `yourDataFrame[ ,2]` that are greater than 5.

Comment: In case the OP wants to `sum` for all other columns, `colSums(df[df[,2] >5,-2])`